# Displaying items from Google SpreadSheet. Text Formatting issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using JavaScript to get data from a spreadsheet and outputting to a html file. It is only retrieving the most recent input which is what i want.

The website will display

```
"12/3/2016 12:49:10
"Katelynn Logan"
"more output"
"..."
 and so on.
```

My end goal is to have it all neat where its like

```
"Date:       Tested by:      blahblah:    other text:

12/03/2016     name           string         int or what
```

you get the idea. Right now its outputting every cell below the previous one.
Is there a way to make a template of the format you desire and it will output the information following the layout of that format?

```
date:           name:          PH

current date    billybob       7.6

then output to next line
```

and so on. Or better yet,

```
Column A     B      C
       D     E      F
       H     I      J
```

[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Y5Syg-z63YGfsX7nPYOXRFZ-t_jB23QUKCLZAT4BYA/edit#gid=1833266067) is where its getting the information. There's years of data in there so I apologize for the long scroll down

and here is the code where it outputs it.

```
var range = response.result;
var row = range.values[range.values.length-1];
          // Print columns A and AO, which correspond to indices 0 and 40.
    for(i=0; i<40; i++){ // 
          appendPre(row[i]);
 }
```

Comment: What's appendPre?

Comment: the javascript is adding to the html <pre> tags with an Id "output"

Comment: You could write another function that puts the output betwen `<td>` and `</td>` and build a table around it

Comment: You may want to check and try using other methods of [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) to get data from the spreadsheet such as [`setDataValidation(rule)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationrule) wherein this sets one data-validation rule from all cells in the range or [`getDataValidations()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatavalidations) which returns the data-validation rules for all cells in the range.